# PIG Split relation into groups of n elements

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

Given a relation I need to group them into groups of n elements. Is that possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can group relations by multiple fields, such as:

```
A = GROUP A BY (f1, f2, f3);
```

Also, you can specify tuples in group by fields like this:

```
A = GROUP A BY (f1, (f2,f3));
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot generate say groups of 50 elements right?

Comment: @Altober sorry. I cannot understand what you want to do. Would you show me your problem with example?

Comment: I have a relation with 10 tuples. I want to get 5 bags of 2 tuples each.

Comment: Do you mean 10 rows of tuple? then I think you can group all tuples and pass them to UDF which group them every 2 tuples. 
A = group A all;
A = udf.groupEveryTwoTuples( A );

Comment: Ah OK, I have to do it myself, I thought that probably there was a direct way of doing it with the split function or so. Thanks.